# Java translator for println usages to convenient logger

Tags: java, logging, automation, static-analysis

I often see (and reuse) 3rd party source code that doesn't have appropriate output. Is there any tool (code translator) that convert `println` output to suitable log framework code

```
private void processCreateTraining() {
    System.out.println("Training set created");
    //..
}
```

to something like

```
private void processCreateTraining() {
    LOG.info("Training set created");
    //..
}
```

It could be done by search-and-replace or Structural Replace in IDEA. But is there more sophisticated/robust solution that provide more flexibility: different logging framework support, ask severity on occurrence replace, string concatenation via `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I doubt it :). I use the "kick their ass into compliance" method but this is not always available so i end up with your solution. On a second thought this could be a very good idea for an IDEA plugin :).

Comment: uh no... that's what project standards are for.

Answer (score 0):

If I come across third party libraries that use `println` all over the place, I tend NOT to use it.  It is a sign of poor workmanship, and that implies (to me) that there are likely to be other more insidious problems with the code.

But no, I'm not aware of any plugin or tool to deal specifically with this case.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WrappedOutputStream los = new WrappedOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(los, true));
    System.out.println("catch me");
}
```

**WrappedOutputStream.java**

```
class WrappedOutputStream extends ByteArrayOutputStream { 
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        String str = "WRAPPED: " + this.toString();
        // process
    }
}
```